# FedEx and USPS are not working in 1.9CE

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

Neither FedEx nor USPS shipping methods seem to be functioning in 1.9CE. Does anyone else have experience resolving this issue? I have upgraded two sites from 1.4CE (which were using FedEx and USPS) and now I can only offer flat rate. What next?

Comment: Have you re-entered your FEDEX and USPS credentials? During the upgrade, they may have been changed accidentally (due to encryption keys). This has happened to me before.  What do your var/logs say about it? Turn on debug mode on Fedex.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in July 28, 2013 USPS make some changes to own API and you should install patches to USPS module of Magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/magento-community-edition-alert-important-patch-for-usps-api/ 
And also FEDEX api also was changed in May, 2012. Use updated extension: http://www.webshopapps.com/fedex-shipping.html

If you have already updated your modules, see var/logs/ to find some issues.

Comment: Do I need to install patches if my site was installed in 2014? I checked the USPS log and it says: <Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>

Comment: The USPS login is correct though...

Comment: FedEx log says:     [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
            [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Severity] => ERROR
                    [Source] => prof
                    [Code] => 1000
                    [Message] => Authentication Failed
                )

Comment: But the FedEx credentials are also correct...

Comment: please your site link or check my profile to send thanks

Comment: http://sunbeltoptic.com/1.9/magento/